# Simple question for sequence : What is the negation of this statement?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logic

What is the negation of the following statement?

> There is a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ in $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> (i) $x_{n}\neq c$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
>
> (ii) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=c$, and
>
> (iii) $\{f(x_{n})\}$ does not exist.

I'm confusing to negate the above statement because there are three conditions to be satisfied.

Is it true the following is a negation of the statement?

> For any $l\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ in $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=c$ with $x_{n}\neq c$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_{n})=l$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broken down, your statement is essentially like

$$ \exists x\in S, \phi_1(x) \wedge\phi_2(x) \wedge \phi_3(x)$$

where $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$, and $\phi_3$ corresponds to i, ii, and iii, respectively. Here $S$ is defined as the collection of all sequences in $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

The negation, therefore, is

$$ \forall x \in S, (\lnot \phi_1(x))\vee(\lnot\phi_2(x))\vee(\lnot(\phi_3(x))$$

That is, the negation is: "For all sequences in $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, at least one of the conditions above do not hold".

Your version is like the negation above, but with the disjunctions $\vee$ swapped with conjunctions $\wedge$.